# Java - Subtract 32 from a number in a specific amount of time

Tags: java, numbers

I was wondering... Is there a way that I could subtract 32 from a number in a specific amount of time?  Such as 500 mils?
If you could help out, it would be great!

Thanks!

```
public void update() {
x += dx;

if(this.y % 32 == 0) {
    this.tileY = this.y / 32;
}

if(this.x % 32 == 0) {
    this.tileX = this.x / 32;
}

System.out.println(tileX);

    }

 public void moveLeft () {
// subtract 32 dx in 500 ms
 }
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(500L)? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have a variable (dx) and I'm working on a tile based game, so I need to subtract 32 dx in a certain amount of time to move left :)

Comment: The question is much too vague. The correct solution depends on what you UI framework you use (Swing, other?). Show us your code.

Comment: Okay, I'm using swing...  I'm about to post my code above.

Comment: Do you need the 32 to be subtracted all in one go at the end of your 500ms or slowly over the period of 500ms?

Comment: Over a period of 500ms :)

Comment: so a sliding animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a lovely code I've developed for you. I've added the keyword `static` to be able to call it from `main` without creating any objects, but it does not use anything from a static context.

As my comments through the code try to explain, this isn't the perfect solution, it's just a start, you may face issues such as multi-threading errors (if you decide to use a separate Thread to update the position) or slight timing issues if the body of the method takes a while to execute.

If you feel the nanosecond precision is a bit too much for your purposes, remember there is also `Thread.sleep(int milis)`.

Here is the code (try changing the values calling `moveLeft(int, int)` to see the results):

```
public class Slider {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*
             * If you are going to use something like this, beware you are multi-threading
             * Make sure what you do is thread-safe
             */
            moveLeft(32, 500);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
  }

  public static void moveLeft(int distance, int milis) {
    //time_px is how many nanoseconds the Thread can sleep until it has to move 1 dx
    double time_px = (100000*milis)/distance;
    if (time_px >= 1) {
        //Get the milis and nanos, rounding for Thread.sleep
        long time_round = (long) Math.floor(time_px);
        long milis_sleep = time_round/100000;
        System.out.print("Waiting " + milis_sleep + "ms ");
        int nano_sleep = (int) (time_round%100000); 
        System.out.println(nano_sleep + "ns per dx");
        for (int i=0; i<distance; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(milis_sleep, nano_sleep);
                /*
                 * Your code here
                 * A long code here might not get you the desired result since the sleeping does
                 * not account for the time spent processing the code. But this is a good start
                 */
                System.out.println("moving 1 dx");
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Cannot go that fast");
        //If you are moving that fast (more than 1 dx per nanosecond) then you need to change this up a little.
    }
  }
}
```